# Retyped.chartist usage unclear. How do I create a basic line chart?

Tags: javascript, c#, bridge, chartist.js, bridge.net

I'm using bridge.NET and [Retyped](https://retyped.com/), I have [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) as a js library and also I have Retyped.chartist as a nuget package in visual studio (this maps c# code to the js lib).
When I run the website The library is loaded. But my code doesnt work:

```
chartist.Chartist2.Line.New(newUsersChart, new Chartist.IChartistData
        {
            labels = arr,
            series = arr2
        });
```

The error is that Chartist2 is undefined. Tried to access Line on undefined.
I tried looking trough the retyped mapping, but no luck. Nothing found over the internet about this specific scenario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the **Bridge CLI** installed and used the following commands to create a demo project (on Mac):

```
mkdir demo1
cd demo1
bridge new
bridge add package retyped.chartist
bridge build
bridge run
code .
```

The call to `code .` opens the project in Visual Studio Code.

Within **Program.cs**, I used the following C#:

```cs
using System;
using Bridge;
using Retyped;
using static Retyped.chartist;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new Chartist.IChartistData
            {
                labels = new es5.Array<string>("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"),
                series = new es5.Array<es5.Array<double>>(new es5.Array<double>(5, 2, 4, 2, 0 ))
            };

            var options = new Chartist.ILineChartOptions
            {
                width = 300,
                height = 200
            };

            Chartist2.Line.New(".ct-chart", data, options);
        }
    }
}
```

Not the cleanest or most obvious C#, but it's what's currently required to get this working. Hopefully at some point in the future Retyped can improve the C# to allow for use of more natural and common C# classes, such as anonymous objects and basic C# arrays.

This demo is based on a sample provided in the Chartist [Getting Started](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html) doc.

The following `loader` config section is also required in the projects **bridge.json** file:

```
"loader": {
  "manualLoading": "true",
  "skipManualVariables": "true"
}
```

In the /dist folder, I then created a new **demo.html** file and added the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.8/chartist.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.8/chartist.js"></script>

    <script src="bridge.js"></script>
    <script src="demo1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Rebuild the project.

If you go back to the browser and view **demo.html**, the Chartist chart should render correctly.

Hope this helps.